# onPostExecute() isn't getting invoked when the AsyncTask is executed from a nested event listener

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here's what I am trying to do: Fetch a JSON array from a remote server and render it in a list view (in a new activity) when an item is selected from a list of items in a popup. The popup is created when an element in an activity is clicked/tapped. To be more specific: an activity displays a list of categories in a grid view. Each category has a bunch of subcategories that are shown as a list of items in a popup when the user clicks on a category. When the user selects one of the items in the popup a new activity is created that displays the list of items in that subcategory. The item details are fetched from a remote server as a JSON array.
I have created an AsyncTask to fetch the item details from the server when a sub-category is selected from the popup. Following is the code snippet for this.

```
public class Section extends Fragment {
    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, final View v, nt position, long id) {
                ...

                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), v);

                ...

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        new GetProductDataFromServer_Task().execute(productURL);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductListScreen.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        return true;
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The Fragment is part of an activity that is used to display the category list in a grid layout.

And, here is the AsyncTask that fetches the JSONArray from the server.

```
private class GetProductDataFromServer_Task extends AsyncTask < String, Long, JSONObject > {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String...params) {
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

        HttpGet httpGet = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        if (httpEntity != null) {
          try {
                String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(entityResponse);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        try {
            JSONArray products = jsonObject.getJSONArray("products");
            int numProducts = products.length();
            mProductList = new ProductInfoForGridView[numProducts];
            for (int prodIdx = 0; prodIdx < numProducts; prodIdx++) {
                mProductList[prodIdx] = GetProductObjFromJSONObj(products.getJSONObject(prodIdx));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue that I am facing is that onPostExecute() isn't getting invoked for some reason. The JSONArray is getting fetched from the server successfully and doInBackground() function completes its execution without any exceptions. I suspect that this has something to do with nested event listeners since it works just fine if I start the Async task from the category listener (i.e. in onItemClick() - the function that invokes the nested sub-category listener, setOnMenuItemClickListener()).

Thanks in advance for your answer. I have tried to be descriptive in my question. I will be glad to provide more details if required.

Comment: are you executing the asynctask from the main (UI) thread? otherwise onPostExecute won't get called.

Comment: Here is the navigation flow: Launch Screen -> Category Screen (implements horizontal paging - creates and assigns one fragment per tab) -> Fragment:onCreateView -> mGrid.setOnItemClickListener:onItemClick() -> popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener:onMenuItemClick() -> (new GetProductDataFromServer_Task().execute(productURL);) . My understanding is that all the activities leading to the creation of the AsyncTask are happening on the UI thread. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: An update...I don't see the issue that I reported earlier when i introduce a delay of about 2 seconds between the start of AsynTask and the start of the Activity that uses the data fetched by AsyncTask from the remote server. What I infer from this behavior is that the network delay has a definite role to play in preventing the Android framework from invoking onPostExecute(). The way I am planning to deal with this is by displaying a "loading..." message till the time I receive all the data and then start the new activity. I would appreciate if someone can suggest a better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `onPostExecute` not running. Have you tried 
`yourGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onPostExecute`